# Does the combination of words “Goals” Challenge together make sense?

Tags: correlative-constructions

I’m looking for domain name for project. It’s basically a challenge that you have to accept and get your goals done. I came up with Goals Challenge, but my friend told me that those two words together don’t make any sense, as those are synonyms. What do you think? What if I put like “Goals” Challenge, means “Goals” is a name of the challenge.

Comment: domain names means: .za/.fr/.com etc. for the internet. Goals and challenges are not synonyms. I agree that Goals Challenge is fine.

Comment: try **challenginggoals**

Comment: Not sure this is really on topic.  After all, "google" doesn't make sense, not does "StackExchange" so domain names don't have to "make sense".

Answer (score 2):

'Goal' and 'challenge' are not synonyms. Reaching a goal or goals can be a challenge.

> goal noun [ C ] (AIM) ​ B1 an aim or purpose:

[Goal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goal)

> challenge noun (INVITATION) ​ [ C ] an invitation to compete or take
>   part, especially in a game or argument

[Challenge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/challenge)